# Trick to quickly find file & line number throwing an error in Go?

Tags: debugging, go, stack-trace, aws-lambda

In my journey with go discovered that there are no stacktraces. so whenever something breaks, all we get an simple string error message without any information where is this is coming from. This is in stark contrast with other languages where I am used to [seing detailed stacktraces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAUSD.png)

For example, below is the error message from [apex](https://github.com/apex/apex)

```
$ cat event.json | apex invoke --logs webhook                                  
   ⨯ error parsing response: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
```

here its telling me that unmarshal to a map ins't working because `event.json` is an array. We have unmarshal to `interface{}` to support both arrays & maps.However, it doesn't tell me which file/line is causing this error.

**Questions:**

1. What is way to quickly find which file/line this error coming from?
2. In General, Are there tips/tricks which gophers use to get to the source of problem quickly from this string error message?
3. is this how stack traces are for most go projects or there are any best practices that should be followed?

Comment: If you're interested I would encourage you to read this blog post. https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go . Go doesn't "throw" errors, it returns them. If you imagine handing somebody a form, if you made a mistake with the form they shouldn't throw it up in the air and crash the whole office. They should tell you what you did wrong. The latter is what happened here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is way to quickly find which file/line this error coming from?

There are no default stacks printed unless it's an unrecovered panic.

> In General, Are there tips/tricks which gophers use to get to the source of problem quickly from this string error message? is this how stack traces are for most go projects or there are any best practices that should be followed?

In General, you need to check error returns from most of the function calls. There are more than one way to do that.
I usually use standard library package `log` to print out error logs with file and line numbers for easy debugging in simple programs. For example:

```
package main

import "log"
import "errors"

func init() { log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile | log.LstdFlags) }

func callFunc() error {
    return errors.New("error")
}

func main() {
    if err := callFunc(); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/0iytNw7eZ7

output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 main.go:14: error
```

Also, there are functions for you to print or retrieve current stacks in standard library `runtime/debug`, e.g. https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#PrintStack

There are many community efforts on bringing error handling easier, you can search error in GoDoc: https://godoc.org/?q=error

Answer (score 2):

**Your attempted *solution*:** Finding the piece of code that produces the error to fix the code.

**Your actual *problem*:** The content of `event.json`.

<sub>This is called the [X-Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)</sub>

---

Invoke expects a json object, you are passing a json array. Fix that and your problem is gone!

```
$ echo -n '{ "value": "Tobi the ferret" }' | apex invoke uppercase
```

Relevant part of the documentation: [Invoking Functions](http://apex.run/#invoking-functions)

And that's the piece of code that produces the error: [Github](https://github.com/apex/apex/blob/8ae0929b54e6e47902c32e7431c47d48c6cd098d/cmd/apex/invoke/invoke.go#L67)

---

And yes, Go does have stack traces! Read [Dave Cheneys blog post on errors and exceptions](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/01/18/why-go-gets-exceptions-right).

Answer (score 1):

Go *does* produce stack traces when a `panic` happens, crashing the program. This will happen if the code calls `panic()` directly, typically in cases like:

```
if err != nil {
    panic("it broke")
}
```

or, when a runtime error happens:

```
a := []int{1, 2, 3}
b := a[12] // index out of range
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
package main

func main() {
    panic("wtf?!")
}
```

Output:

```
panic: wtf?!

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x94e60, 0x1030a040)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x700
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox366642315/main.go:4 +0x80
```

Note the `main.go:4` indicating the filename and line number.

In your example, the program *did not* panic, instead opting to call (I'm guessing) `os.Exit(1)` or `log.Fatal("error message")` (which calls `os.Exit(1)`). Or, the panic was simply recovered from in the calling function. **Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do about this if you aren't the author of the code.**

I would recommend reading [Defer, Panic, and Recover](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) on the Golang blog for more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)` in main() should do it.

For example, `log.Printf("Deadline!")` would print:

> 03/11/2020 23:59:59 liberty_test.go:42: Deadline!

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the error, and figure out what type it is, and from that you can access the Offset value eg:

```golang
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(f)
    switch err := decoder.Decode(&cfg).(type) {
    case *json.SyntaxError:
        log.Panicf("Parse Error @%d\n", err.Offset)
    }
```

I have also written a helper for files to read teh file and map the offset to a line no and position:

```golang
type FilePos struct {
    line int
    pos  int
}

func findPos(file *bufio.Reader, offset int) FilePos {
    p := FilePos{line: 1, pos: offset}
    var lineLen int
    for line, err := file.ReadBytes('\n'); len(line) > 0 && err == nil; line, err = file.ReadBytes('\n') {
        if p.pos < len(line) {
            return p
        }
        lineLen += len(line)
        if line[len(line)-1] == '\n' {
            p.line += 1
            p.pos -= lineLen
            lineLen = 0
        }
    }
    return p
}
```

which can be used as follows:

```golang
    f, err := os.Open("myfile.json")
    ...
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(f)
    switch err := decoder.Decode(&cfg).(type) {
    case *json.SyntaxError:
        f.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
        pos := findPos(bufio.NewReader(f), int(err.Offset))
        log.Panicf("Unable to decode configuration file (Line: %d, Pos: %d); - %v\n", pos.line, pos.pos, err.Error())
    }
```

This will only work on seekable streams, eg files. For network data you would have to keep a full in a buffer to use this.